# XSLT replace repeating text

Tags: xml, xslt

For a field I have text that is repeating itself for each node I have connected to it, like this

**Original output**

```
;#{1220}Price:  ;#{1231}1x59 kr;#{1291}1x21 kr;#{1253}2x10 kr;#{1254}1x600 kr;#
```

Price is here the root node, the subsequent ones are subnodes. I am interested in removing the ;#{NODEID} and the rootnode title from all the nodes so that the output will be:

**Wanted output**

```
1x59 kr, 1x21 kr, 2x10 kr, 1x600 kr
```

Mind I want the ;# removed from the end aswell.

I have achieved to remove the rootnode title, but I do not know how to remove it from all nodes. I should add I am very new to xslt. I use the following to remove the rootnode title:

```
<xsl:template name="FormatPrice" match="FieldRef[@Name='lookup']" mode="Lookup_body" >
<xsl:param name="lookupVal" />
<xsl:param name="clnVal"/>
<xsl:param name="index" select="0"/>

<xsl:variable name="concatinateClean">
  <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="$clnVal =null or $clnVal ='' or $clnVal =' '">
      <xsl:value-of select="$clnVal"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($lookupVal,';#') and $index mod 2=1">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($clnVal, '')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$clnVal"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="contains($lookupVal,';#')">
  <xsl:variable name="firstHshRem" select="substring-after($lookupVal, ';#')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="afterSecondHash" select="substring-after($firstHshRem, ';#')" />
  <xsl:variable name="remNodeID" select="substring($afterSecondHash, 7)" />


  <xsl:variable name="tempClean">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$index mod 2 = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$concatinateClean"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($concatinateClean,$remNodeID)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="temporary">
    <xsl:call-template name="FormatPrice">
      <xsl:with-param name="lookupVal" select="$firstHshRem"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="clnVal" select="$tempClean"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index+1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$temporary"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(contains($lookupVal,';#'))">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($concatinateClean,$lookupVal)"/>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**

Thank you Marcus for your help, and apologies for my late reply. I am getting very close now.

I edited the code you provided to some extent, due to I am using Sharepoint and I am searching in a termstore-field. I forgot to mention I need to hide more than one header. I have one Price header and one Location header.

Output is now as follows:

```
, Price:, 1x59 kr, 1x21 kr, 2x10 kr, 1x600 kr 
, Location:, Bermuda, Tenerife
```

with the following code:

```
<xsl:template name="FormatPL" match="FieldRef[@Name='lookup']" mode="Lookup_body" >
<xsl:param name="lookupVal" />

    <xsl:choose>

  <xsl:when test="contains($lookupVal, ';#{')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($lookupVal, ';#')"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="FormatPL">
      <xsl:with-param name="lookupVal" select="substring-after(substring-after($lookupVal, ';#'), '}')"/>    
    </xsl:call-template>        
  </xsl:when>


  <xsl:when test="contains($lookupVal, ';#')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($lookupVal, ';#')"/>
  </xsl:when>

  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$lookupVal"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Calling the search with:

```
 <td>
    <h3>
       Price:
    </h3>
 </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <xsl:call-template name="FormatPL">
         <xsl:with-param name="lookupVal" select="@ows_PL" />
       </xsl:call-template>                
   </p>
 </td>
</tr>
```

where @ows_PL is the field in sharepoint, and I use the same for Location.

I realise this is basic stuff, but I am having a hard time to do this. I now only need to remove the ",  Price:," and ", Location:," at the start. Any further help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It would be better if you also provide source XML.

Comment: What is `concat($clnVal, '')` supposed to do?

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, Marcus. I am nearly there. I have edited my original post, and just need to get rid of the starting text as explained in the post.

Comment: My answer already contains what you need: use a `substring-after` when you pass the string to the template `FormatPL`: `<xsl:with-param name="lookupVal" select="substring-after(@ows_PL, ':')" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an input XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <price>;#{1220}Price:  ;#{1231}1x59 kr;#{1291}1x21 kr;#{1253}2x10 kr;#{1254}1x600 kr;#</price>
</root>
```

the following XSLT will generate the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="price">
    <result>
      <xsl:call-template name="FormatPriceRecursive">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(substring-after(text(), 'Price:  '), '}')"/>    
      </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="FormatPriceRecursive">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>

    <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="contains($text, ';#{')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, ';#')"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="FormatPriceRecursive">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(substring-after($text, ';#'), '}')"/>    
        </xsl:call-template>        
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="contains($text, ';#')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, ';#')"/>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I made the following assumptions:

- the prefix of the price string up to `Price:` can be ignored
- a line is always terminated by `;#`

Comment: Thank you, your help was greatly appreciated. <xsl:with-param name="lookupVal" select="substring-after(@ows_PL, ':')" /> did the trick